# How to flash AT&T UNIX to cd, floppy or (preferably) USB?

Tags: historical-unix

Preferably USB as it would be easier to carry arround and install on other systems

I have never used Unix.

My first PC was a windows XP laptop when I was about 8 years old. i have installed Linux, DOS, Windows 95 and a lot of other things.

Unfortunately I cannot find any information on flashing Unix to a USB or the order of flashing it to a CD or floppy disk.

Is there anyone who knows how one would achieve this? I have a wide range of old hardware that sounds perfect for a Unix cluster of some kind but can't find any info on how to flash Unix to some installation media.

Comment: Although this specific Q is acceptable here, Qs about resurrecting old systems and software are likely to find more interested and informed respondents on https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com which is specifically focussed on that topic.

Answer (score 0):

Not at all.

If you actually mean *AT&T UNIX* as marketed with the computer of the same name:
The AT&T UNIX was a 1985 operating system for the *AT&T UNIX PC*, and that was a Motorola 68010 CPU, which has no real similarity with the x86 CPU or ARM CPU that your modern PC or laptop has.

Maybe you mean "Research UNIX", which is what the AT&T Bell Labs Computing Sciences Research Center developed in the early 1970s, and which AT&T marketed under the AT&T trademark to universities starting with its 1974 release of the 5th edition.
But that not only predates the IBM PC architecture by roughly a decade, it could never run on any machine that had a CPU that's similar to x86 or ARM. So, also clearly not what you could run on your old machines, unless you forget to mention that you have a PDP-11, a VAX or an Interdata 8/32 standing around, in an extra wing of your house. By the way, these predate floppy drives, CDROMs and USB by a couple decades :)

[image: PDP-11]
<sup>This is what a computer that ran AT&T's Research Unix and later Editions looked like: a PDP-11. Source: Stefan_Kögl, CC BY-SA 3.0 from https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Pdp-11-40.jpg . Notice the distinct lack of floppy disk drives, CD-ROM drives, SCSI, SATA or USB interfaces. Due to a case of unforeseen causality, these were not yet invented.</sup>

Maybe, you mean "Unix 7th Edition" from 1979. Itself, as far as I know, it never ran on x86, but Xenix, a Microsoft-licensed derivative/Port of that ran on the intel 8086, so it still wouldn't run on a modern machine (sensibly). "Unix 8th edition", 9th and the final 10th edition as far as I know had no influence on XENIX, so, are completely unrelated to any hardware you might have standing around. To be fair, Xenix ran on the IBM PC AT, and [SCO XENIX 2.3 ran on 386](https://www.pcjs.org/software/pcx86/sys/unix/sco/xenix/386/2.3.4h/), so it is probably able to run on your PC, if you really really try. You don't need more than 2 MB of RAM for anything, do you? Also, networking with your networking hardware or TCP/IP sounds unlikely. So, not "clusterable".

So, your computers simply cannot execute any UNIX or UNIX derivative ever developed by AT&T (aside from Bell Labs' Plan9, which was publicly released after Bell Labs was bought by Lucent, but small-circle available to universities earlier while the Bell Labs still belonged to AT&T; anyways, Plan9 is *not* a UNIXoid in my understanding) themselves.
Thus, you could run it on none of them, even if you had it on a medium that these computers know to load bootloaders from, and even if any AT&T UNIX magically had acquired the ability to talk to such hardware posthumously.

If any of your machines have USB, run Linux, Open-, Free- or NetBSD, Minix, OpenSolaris… Ancient UNIX ran on machines that really don't resemble what you've got your hands on.

> I have a wide range of old hardware that sounds perfect for a Unix cluster of some kind but can't find any info on how to flash Unix to some installation media.

I promise that aside from Plan 9, none of the AT&T-descendant UNIXes will make you happy in a cluster environment. And Plan9 is very special, in that it intentionally deviates a lot from classic UNIX in a lot of ways. In some ways, using a modern Linux is closer than Plan9.

Comment: CDROM _existed_ a few years after 7ed, but didn't become _common_ until 1990ish. _Floppy disks_ were common in the 1970s, including on PDP-11 (RX01 and RX02) -- but they were the 8" floppies invented for IBM 3741, also used on some early microcomputers like IMSAI, not the 5.25" and then 3.5" ones used on IBM and compatible (Wintel) PCs. Early floppies didn't have capacity to be a Unix root disk; when we reached 1.4MB it might just have been possible. (The first Unix I used was 6ed on one 2.5MB RK05-J and could re-sysgen itself, barely.)